# Trigger Testing Issue

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Im just fleshing out the logic here before tiding it up. For the life of me I cannot figure out why this isn't working. The Primary__c is being changed in the trigger but it is not asserting that is has in the test method?? Could it be a permissions issue on the Primary__c field?

Trigger Class

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) {
System.debug('== Contact Trigger Firing Now ==');

private double maxCommission = 0.0;
private integer newPrimaryIndex;

if(Trigger.new.size() != null){
    for(Contact aContact : Trigger.new){
        if(aContact.Primary__c == true){
            aContact.Primary__c = false;
        }
        if(aContact.Total_Commission_Earned__c > maxCommission){
            maxCommission = aContact.Total_Commission_Earned__c;
            newPrimaryIndex = Trigger.new.indexOf(aContact);
        }
    }

    if(newPrimaryIndex != null){
        Trigger.new[newPrimaryIndex].Primary__c = true;
        System.debug(Trigger.new[newPrimaryIndex].id);
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class TestCommissionTrigger {
    @isTest static void TestUpdateCommission() {
        // Test data setup
        Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert acct;
        Contact cont = new Contact(LastName='Doe', Primary__c=false, Account=acct, AccountId=acct.Id );
        insert cont;
        System.debug(cont.Id);

        // Perform test
        Test.startTest();
        Commission__c comm = new Commission__c(Amount__c=2000, Awarded_To__c=cont.Id, Awarded_To__r=cont); //interesting had to explicitly declare __c and __r
        insert comm;
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assert(cont.Primary__c == true);
    }

}
```

Comment: N.B. 1) `if(Trigger.new.size() != null)` can never happen; 2) just unconditionally set `aContact.Is_Primary__c to false`; 3) testmethods of triggers should at least ,mock 2+ recs and verify each is set as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to query data from Contact again after the record is updated in order to retrieve the latest values.

```
    cont = [SELECT Primary__c FROM Contact];             
    System.assert(cont.Primary__c == true);
```

Also: can you confirm via console that the field is being updated on the trigger? If not, I believe you will have to first update cont in order to run the trigger.